# Get selected value of DropDownList in view at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, selectlist

I have two dropDownLists:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Organization, (SelectList)ViewBag.Organizations)
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Doctor, (SelectList)ViewBag.Doctors)
```

The selectList is passed from the controller

```
        List<IOkpolu> orgs = _unitOfWork.Organizations.ToList();
        ViewBag.Organizations = new SelectList(orgs, "Code", "Name");

        List<IDoctor> docs = _unitOfWork.Doctors.GetAll().ToList();
        ViewBag.Doctors = new SelectList(docs, "Code", "Name");
```

I want to load the second DropDownList (Doctors) with values based on the Code of organization is choosen in the first DropDownList at runtime.
For Doctors I have method that takes Doctors from organization:

```
_unitOfWork.Doctors.GetByOrganization(string organizationCode)
```

How can I get the value selected in the first DropDownList at runtime and pass it to the second DropDownList?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, load your `Doctors` list using the default organization code (first item in your `orgs` list) at runtime.

```
    List<IOkpolu> orgs = _unitOfWork.Organizations.ToList();
    ViewBag.Organizations = new SelectList(orgs, "Code", "Name");

    model.Organization = orgs[0];

    List<IDoctor> docs = _unitOfWork.Doctors.GetByOrganization(model.Organization).ToList();
    ViewBag.Doctors = new SelectList(docs, "Code", "Name");
```